# Can't mount external usb driver on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb, mount

When plug in external usb driver to PC I see next info:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

I tried to use `lsblk`, and after this mount this driver I caught next warning:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 148.1G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  1022M  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part /media/sdb1
sdd      8:48   1   7.2G  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   1   7.2G  0 part 
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ sudo mount /media/sdd
mount: can't find /media/sdd in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

It should work but it doesn't.

Here is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                       /proc           proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid         0  0  
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5f5d330f-d5f2-4157-9496-94f1dce2f181  /               ext4  errors=remount-ro           0  1  
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=84747ef4-6f50-49bc-9df1-fcba364ba299  none            swap  sw                          0  0  

/dev/fd0                                   /media/floppy0  auto  rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8    0  0  
/dev/sdc1                                  /media/sdc1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto,users,exec  0  0  
/dev/sdd1                                  /media/sdd1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto,users,exec  0  0  
/dev/sdb1                                  /media/sdb1     vfat  uid=1000,noauto,users,exec  0  0
```

Here is content of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e28b8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   310484991   155241472   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       310487038   312580095     1046529    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       310487040   312580095     1046528   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes
16 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15296 cylinders, total 7831552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd8e1f237

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32     7831551     3915760    b  W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/sdd: 7751 MB, 7751073792 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 942 cylinders, total 15138816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *          63    15138815     7569376+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

**Update:**

Output of `sudo blkid /dev/sdd1`:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ sudo blkid /dev/sdd1
/dev/sdd1: UUID="E6C05CB9C05C9223" TYPE="ntfs"
```

**Questions:**

- Why exactly this happen (on windows this usb works perfect)?
- How to solve this trouble?

Comment: Please supply the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sdd1` (or whatever name your USB drive was assigned).

Comment: @DavidFoerster I updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Linux tries to mount your USB drive it tries to guess the correct file system (NTFS in this instance) in the same way that blkid does, unless there you tell it to use a specific file system as in your `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdd1    /media/sdd1    vfat    uid=1000,noauto,users,exec  0  0
```

Pay attention to the 1st and 3rd column!

You can work around this manually with the mount command:

```
sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdd1 /media/sdd1
```

A cleaner way would be to replace all instances of `/dev/sd*` by device UUIDs¹, labels, or IDs, because the latter are stable for each device or file system. The former are assigned in the order Linux sees them, which can change especially for removable media.

In most cases you don't want to assign fixed fstab entries for removable media though, only disks inside your computer.

¹ `blkid` or `palimpsest` can tell you device UUIDs

Take a look at the `swap` line in your or an excerpt from my `/etc/fstab` for an example:

```
UUID=84747ef4-6f50-49bc-9df1-fcba364ba299  none    swap  sw    0  0
```

and

```
LABEL=root      /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,discard,noatime  0 1
LABEL=boot      /boot           ext4    defaults,discard,noatime    0       2
LABEL=usr       /usr            ext4    defaults,discard,noatime,data=writeback  0 2
LABEL=var       /var            ext4    defaults,user_xattr,data=writeback  0  2
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   defaults,size=8g,nodev,nosuid,mode=1777  0 0
LABEL=swap1      none           swap    sw,discard,pri=100  0       0

UUID=d7662fe5-04fc-4b4b-a6e0-4d34637d56d3  /home  btrfs  defaults,compress=lzo,space_cache,inode_cache,noatime  0 2
LABEL=scratch   /mnt/scratch    ext4    rw,discard,noatime,data=writeback,user_xattr  0 2

# Windows partitions
LABEL=Windows7  /mnt/win7       ntfs    defaults,ro,nobootwait,noauto,noatime,nls=utf8,norecover,windows_names  0 0
LABEL=Windata   /mnt/windata    ntfs    defaults,ro,nobootwait,noauto,noatime,nls=utf8,norecover,windows_names  0 0

# dm-crypt partitions
UUID=82bf1677-acbf-41dd-814e-08652b2d325b  /home/david/media  crypto_LUKS.ext4  defaults,nobootwait,noauto,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=writeback  0 0
UUID=d4f9d97c-0dd9-4ac8-959f-92818848505b  /mnt/winmedia  crypto_LUKS.ntfs  defaults,ro,nobootwait,noauto,noatime,nls=utf8,norecover,windows_names  0 0
```

Comment: I misunderstand a little bit. Do I have to only this `sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdd1 /media/sdd1` this command for fixing this trouble?

Comment: `sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdd1 /media/sdd1` will work around your problem once. You may have to do that every time you plug a removable drive, if you don't fix it properly.

Comment: I maybe miss smt can you give steps how to fix this step-by-step.

Comment: You probably want to delete the last 3 lines of your fstab. If you're unsure, uncomment them for later reuse.

Comment: It works perfect